# Access to an item of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, items

I am trying to get access to the items of an object, called **verein**. The corresponding code is:

```
export function TestForm(verein) {
    console.log(verein);
    console.log(verein.Verein_Name); // I try to get "Eschweiler Kanu Club e.V.

  return;
}
```

The output is:

```
0
: 
{id: 2, Verein_Name: 'Eschweiler Kanu Club e.V.', Verein_Kurz: 'EKC', Verein_Strasse: 'Ardennenstr. 82', Verein_PLZ: '52076', …}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

I try to access the values of the object, but I haven't found a way to get them. I want to fill some input fields of prime react/inputfields.

```
    <span className="p-float-label">
       <InputText id="in" value={verein.Vereins_Name} disabled={isDisabled} />
       <label htmlFor="in">Vereinsname</label>
```

Comment: Please copy the output as an object literal using right click → “Copy object”.

Comment: ... or log them as JSON `console.log(JSON.stringify(verein, null, 2))`

Comment: It looks like `verein` could be an `Array`. Try it by using `verein[0].Verein_Name`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array. Therefore

```
console.log(verein[0].Verein_Name)
```